# jQuery Cloning Altered Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, clone

I am trying to run jQuery .clone() on content that has just been altered with .html(). However, .clone is copying content from before it was altered. I want to clone the altered content. How do I do this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="cloneThis">This text exists before .html() replaces it.</div>
<div id="cloneHere"></div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
// This function copies #cloneThis content over to #cloneHere
function cloneStuff(){
  $('#cloneThis').clone().appendTo('#cloneHere');
}

function changeThenClone(){
  $("#cloneThis").html("This is new text that should be cloned.", cloneStuff());
}
// When this is run, cloneStuff() clones the old content, not the new content. 
changeThenClone();
```

Here's an identical codepen demonstration if you want to see it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoRWMQ

Why isn't .clone() copying the altered content? How do I make it clone the altered content instead of the old content?

Comment: Just use simply chaining: `$("#cloneThis").html("This is new text that should be cloned.").clone().appendTo('#cloneHere')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `cloneStuff()` before the actual HTML replacement is being done by the `html()` function.

Try this instead:

```
$("#cloneThis").html("This is new text that should be cloned.");
cloneStuff();
```

Also, jQuery `html()` method only accepts 1 argument (the new HTML content), see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/).